# Create a recursive function with counter

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I want to create a recursive function with 2 parameters (steps, number).

Inside the recursion something with the number happens and calls the function again with steps-1 and a new number.

As soon as `steps == 0` I want to increase a counter, so I see how many function calls with steps 0 are encountered, depending on the algorithm within the function.

Is there a way to do this - without global variables or additional parameters, both are not possible!

I tried it with:

```
if not counter in locals():
   counter=0
```

but this doesn't work it says

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'counter' referenced before assignment
```

here the complete code:

```
def IsaacRule(steps, number):


if not counter in locals():
    counter = 0

    if steps == 0:
        counter+=1
        return counter

    if ((number - 1) / 3) % 2 == 1:
        IsaacRule(steps-1, (number - 1) / 3)

    if (number * 2) % 2 == 0:
        IsaacRule(steps-1, number*2)

    return counter
```

with global variable (and counter=0 outside of the function) it works - but I am not allowed to use a global variable

Comment: Is your code in a function?

Comment: It should work with `if not "counter" in locals():`, but I'm not sure you want to be doing this..

Comment: Why don't you add an attribute to the function, then increment that?

Comment: i don't understand your question, Yeah, i think @L3viathan is right, but i don't understand why you don't do cotes, if it doesn't `counter` doesn't exist it will trough an error

Comment: Why isn't counter another argument then?

Comment: @kabanus its a given task with a predefined function(steps, number) which unit tests only call the function and have to pass - no additional parameters or global variable declarations outside of the function

Comment: "why ffs downvoting the post " => well I'm not one of the downvoters but your question was initially missing the necessary context (in this case the function's code) which made it difficult to properly understand and answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to use a custom callable type:

```
class MyRecursiveFunc(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 0
    def __call__(self, steps, numbers):
        if steps == 0:
            self.counter += 1
        results = self.do_something(steps, numbers)
        if some_condition():
            results.extend(self(steps-1, numbers))
        return results

func = MyRecursiveFunc()
results = func(steps, numbers)
print(func.counter)
```

Another one is to turn the infamous 'default mutable arguments' gotcha to your advantage:

```
def IsaacRule(steps, number, _counter=[0]):
    if steps == 0:
        _counter[0] += 1
    else: 
        if ((number - 1) / 3) % 2 == 1:
            IsaacRule(steps-1, (number - 1) / 3)

        if (number * 2) % 2 == 0:
            IsaacRule(steps-1, number*2)

    return _counter[0]
```

or if the only result you care about is the counter, you could just update it when doing the recursive call:

```
def IsaacRule(steps, number):
    if steps == 0:
        return 1

    counter = 0
    if ((number - 1) / 3) % 2 == 1:
        counter += IsaacRule(steps-1, (number - 1) / 3)

    if (number * 2) % 2 == 0:
        counter += IsaacRule(steps-1, number*2)

    return counter
```

Comment: the if's are on the wrong level but removing the tab it worked, didnt think about this - this way it only initializes the counter once!

Comment: @DominikLemberger sorry, fixed the indentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can store counter in function itself:

```
def IsaacRule(steps, number):
    if steps == 0:
        IsaacRule.counter+=1
        return IsaacRule.counter

    if ((number - 1) / 3) % 2 == 1:
        IsaacRule(steps-1, (number - 1) / 3)

    if (number * 2) % 2 == 0:
        IsaacRule(steps-1, number*2)

    return IsaacRule.counter

IsaacRule.counter = 0
print(IsaacRule(10, 1000))
```

Comment: thx this worked not sure why the global variable doesnt, but this does